# Write this function without bitsets

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, dynamic-programming

Trying to write a function that gives all ways to cover a R rows by 2 columns figure, I find this function but uses a approach with bitsets, was wondering how can i do this wihtout using binary operators.
This the function explanation: left_obstacles is a bitset of size R    in which each 1 represents an obstacle in the left column, in which this function generates all possible ways to cover the rest of the  left column using 1x1 and 2x2 blocks, and for each of them it returns    the bitset of cells covered in the right column.

```
def place22blocks(left_obstacles): 

    options = set([ (left_obstacles,0) ])    
    for add in range(R//2):        
      new_options = set()
      for option in options:            
         new_options.add(option)            
         left, right = option            
         for i in range(R-1):                
             if (left & (3<<i)) == 0:    
                 new_options.add( (left | (3<<i), right | (3<<i)) )       
         options = new_options    
    return [ option[1] for option in options ]
```

Comment: Please check the indentation

Comment: @MichaelRuth sorry, just corrected it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your goal is, would the modified version of your function have the same input/output relation or are you wanting to implement the same algorithm with a different data representation?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I'm trying to implement the same algorithm with a different data representation, without using bit operators

Comment: ok but would it make more sense to just convert between representations or is there another reason you want to move away from bitwise? are you running into performance issues with the current way you are handling options because moving away from bitwise won't speed anything up

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have 2 "columns" (variables) that contain obstacles but cannot both contain obstacles in the same "row" (bit)

If this is the case the first observation I would make is that any time there is a blockage in the left column the possible options of the right column on both sides of that blockage are totally independent, in fact if my left column looks something like this:

```
000110000
```

Then really I just need to find all combinations of obstacles for `R=3` and also for `R=4` then the final answer will be the [Cartesian product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of filling those 2 gaps with the combinations.

So first we can write some code to make all possible permutations of obstacles for a given `R` which we can do recursively, you indicated you wanted to move away from bitwise so I'll use tuple concatenation as it will likely be a little easier to manipulate for your actual task than bit operations.

```py
def obstacle_combos(R):
    """
    yields all sequences of obstacles with size 'size' 
    obstacle_patterns is a set of tuples representing different obstacles
    """
    if R==0:
        # cannot fit any blocks of size 0
        yield ()
        return
    if R==1:
        # this ensures the loop below can always check combo[-1] without index error
        yield (0,)
        return
    for combo in obstacle_combos(R-1):
        yield combo + (0,)
        if combo[-1] == 0:
            # when the last element is empty we could instead put a block of 1s as well.
            yield combo[:-1] + (1,1)
        

print(*obstacle_combos(5), sep="\n")
```

The way this works is relatively straight forward, the base case of `R=0` and `R=1` are the trivial case, otherwise we check for `R-1` and that combo with an extra `0` at the end is a valid obstacle combo  for `R`, but also if the last element is `0` we can stick a `11` at the end as well  so that becomes a conditional extra case.

The next step would be to identify runs of consecutive 0s, this is also not particularly complicated we just iterate over the sequence and implement some logic when we switch from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0 etc:

```py
def find_gaps(obstacle_sequence):
    "yields (slice, size) for each range of concecutive 0s in the sequence"
    in_seq = False #whether we are currently in a run of 0s
    for i,elem in enumerate(obstacle_sequence):
        if not in_seq and elem == 0:
            in_seq = True
            start_idx = i
        elif in_seq and elem == 1:
            in_seq = False
            yield slice(start_idx, i), i-start_idx
    # after the loop if the last elements were 0s then yield the final sequence
    if in_seq:
        yield slice(start_idx, len(obstacle_sequence)), len(obstacle_sequence)-start_idx
```

One thing here that is slightly unorthodox is that I am creating `slice` objects directly, this is what happens internally if you do `x[a:b]` it is the same as `x[slice(a,b)]`, the goal here being that later we can use the values this function produces to do something like:

```py
Y = [0]*len(X) # some sequence of same size as X
for idx_range, size in find_gaps(X):
    Y[idx_range] = generate_seq_of_length(size)
```

to set ranges of `Y` (which will end up being our `right_obstacles` eventually) with minimal effort outside the `find_gaps` function.

Now the tricky part, we want a function to take a `left_obstacles` sequence of `1`s and `0`s, find all the runs of `0`s by calling `find_gaps` and at the same time find all the combinations of obstacles we could put in that section. Then go over all [combinations (cartesian product)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of the obstacles that can be laid out in each region.

```py
import itertools
def place22blocks(left_obstacles):
    # start by making a sequence of the same size as left_obstacles
    right_obstacles = [0 for _ in left_obstacles]
    # then we will find all the gaps and setup the obstacle_combos for each one
    gap_ranges = []
    seq_filling_iterators = []
    for idx_range, size in find_gaps(left_obstacles):
        gap_ranges.append(idx_range)
        seq_filling_iterators.append(obstacle_combos(size))
    # at this point each element of seq_filling_iterators is an iterator 
    # that will give the different possibilities of obstacles for each region, 
    # the final result of possible obstacles is the cartesian product of all of them
    for list_of_obstacles_per_gap in itertools.product(*seq_filling_iterators):
        # list_of_obstacles_per_gap is now a list of the sequences to fill in each gap, it is the "generate_seq_of_length(size)" in the previous example essentially.
        for idx_range, seq in zip(gap_ranges, list_of_obstacles_per_gap):
            right_obstacles[idx_range] = seq
        # since we are reusing the right_obstacles variable every loop we will need to make a copy for each valid obstacle list, will make it a tuple so it is immutable but you could also do list(right_obstacles) if you wanted.
        yield tuple(right_obstacles)


print(*place22blocks((0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)),sep="\n")
```

This function I will admit is very complicated to fully wrap your head around for how short it is. `gap_ranges` is the list of ranges where we have space to put obstacles which is parallel to `list_of_obstacles_per_gap` that is the list of sequences, each element matching with the indices stored in `gap_ranges` which is why we zip them together.  The way `list_of_obstacles_per_gap` is generated is a little harder to grasp though, the first thing is that `product` is like a nested loop:

```py
# example loop:
for x in range(5):
    for y in ["a","b","c"]:
        for z in range(10):
            things = (x,y,z)
# that would be equivalent to 
for things in itertools.product(range(5), ["a","b","c"], range(10)):
    pass
```

so an example that might help would be to think about how the code would work if there were exactly 2 gaps to put obstacles:

```py
for obs_seq1 in obstacle_combos(3):
    for obs_seq2 in obstacle_combos(4):
        right_obstacles[0:3] = obs_seq1
        right_obstacles[5:9] = obs_seq2
        print(right_obstacles)
```

so in the function above the outer loop is collapsing an arbitrary number of nested loops and the inner loop is performing all those sequence assignments.

No idea if any of this will actually help you, I'm still not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish but I had fun working through this, happy coding :)

---

Also note if you wanted to implement this more efficient algorithm with bitwise operations that would be very doable as well:

```py
import itertools

def obstacle_combos(R):
    """
    yields all sequences of obstacles with size 'size' 
    obstacle_patterns is a set of tuples representing different obstacles
    """
    if R<=1:
        # cannot fit any blocks of size 0
        yield 0
        return
    for c in obstacle_combos(R-1):
        # shift the original combo so that we are inserting at the least significant bits, 
        # is a little simpler than tracking how much to shift the 3 by.
        combo = c<<1 
        yield combo
        if combo&3 == 0:
            # when the last element is empty we could instead put a block of 1s as well.
            yield combo | 3
        

#print(*obstacle_combos(5), sep="\n")

def find_gaps(obstacle_sequence, R):
    "yields (slice, size) for each range of consecutive 0s in the sequence, where slice is the bit position of the least significant bit that is 0"
    in_seq = False #whether we are currently in a run of 0s
    for i in range(R):
        elem = obstacle_sequence & (1<<i)
        if not in_seq and elem == 0:
            in_seq = True
            start_idx = i
        elif in_seq and elem > 0:
            in_seq = False
            yield start_idx, i-start_idx
    # after the loop if the last elements were 0s then yield the final sequence
    if in_seq:
        yield start_idx, R-start_idx

def place22blocks(left_obstacles, R):
    # start by making a sequence of the same size as left_obstacles
    gap_ranges = []
    seq_filling_iterators = []
    for idx_range, size in find_gaps(left_obstacles, R):
        gap_ranges.append(idx_range)
        seq_filling_iterators.append(obstacle_combos(size))
    
    for list_of_obstacles_per_gap in itertools.product(*seq_filling_iterators):
        yield sum(x<<i for i,x in zip(gap_ranges, list_of_obstacles_per_gap))

print("\n\n")
print(*map("{:09b}".format, place22blocks(0b000110000, 9)),sep="\n")
```